# Даны два одномерных массива из n и m элементов соответственно. Требуется найти общие элементы этих массивов

Tags: c++, массивы

````
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int a[100],n, m, c[100];  //Объявление переменных и массива
cin >> n;
//Ввод первого массива
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
       cin >> a[i];
 cin >> m;
//Ввод второго массива
for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
       cin >> c[j];
//Переменная - граница цикла для проверки
 int x = m;
 if(n > m){
   x = n;
 }
//Цикл проверки, но я не понимаю как его нормально сделать
 for (int v = 0; v < x; v++)
   if (a[i] == c[j]){
     
    return 0;
}  ```
````

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Отсортируйте оба массива, а потом просто идите по двум массивам. Элемент меньше в первом? Сдвигаемся по первому. Во втором? по второму. Равны? Вот он, общий - выводим...

Comment: imho быстрее отсортировать короткий массив (размером n) и за один просмотр длинного (размером m) найти общие элементы *двоичным поиском* (время O(n * log n + m * log n), а для поиска с 2-мя отсортированными массивами O(n * log n + m * log m))